# How can we output the indices j and k that identify the maximum subarray

Tags: algorithm

Maximum Subarray Problem

Given an array of n integers, find the subarray, A[j:k] that maximizes the sum as

[image: Data]

[image: algorithm]

requirement : 
How can we output the indices j and k that
identify the maximum subarray A[j : k]

Please help me out
thanks

Comment: Implement this code in some popular language and we will be able to help you. BTW, the best algo requires only single loop traversal through array. In general case you have to implement own `max` operation with retrieving index values.

Answer (score 0):

The first solution that came to my mind instantly was: Instead of storing a single value in `M`, you can use an object like below:

```
 struct M {
        float sum,
        int start_index,
        int end_index
    }
```

Now change your algorithm as below to work with `M` object:

```
Algorithm MaxSubFastest2(A):
    M[0] = {0, 1, 0}
    for t in 1 to n do:
        if M[t-1]+A[t] > 0:
            M[t] = {M[t-1]+A[t], M[t-1].start_index, M[t-1].end_index+1}
        else:
           M[t] = {0, 1, 0}
    m = 0
    start_index = 0
    end_index = 0
    for t in 1 to n do:
        if M[t].sum > m:
            m = M[t].sum
            start_index = M[t].start_index
            end_index = M[t].end_index

    if start_index <= end_index:
        subarray exists => return m, start_index, end_index
    subarray does not exist => error
```

This algorithm has the same time complexity as above, **but will use extra memory**.

A **more memory optimized version** is here:

```
Algorithm MaxSubFastest3(A):
    max_so_far = 0
    max_ending_here = 0
    start =0
    end = 0
    s=0

    for i in 1 to n: 
        max_ending_here += A[i]
        if max_so_far < max_ending_here:
            max_so_far = max_ending_here
            start = s
            end = i

        if max_ending_here < 0:
            max_ending_here = 0
            s = i + 1
    output max_so_far, start, end
```

This takes up same time and memory as the one in question.

You can find other variations of the same algorithm [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-sum-contiguous-subarray/).

Plus, I notice that the algorithm you've given in the question will always produce 0 as maximum sum for a list full of -ve numbers. I wonder if that is the expected behavior..

Comment: Thanks for the help - Actually i have to embed A[j : k] somewhere in my Maxsubfastest algorithm and i am unable to adjust or inset J:k into it.

Comment: What do you mean by embed? The above algorithm records`j, k` values for all sub-array sums, is it not the behavior you desire?

Comment: I also have edited my post -- added a memory optimized version of the same algorithm

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience , actually i am new to algorithm, and this is my assignment that "How can we output the indices j and k that identify the maximum subarray A[j : k]" thanks

Comment: I suggest you put in some initial effort on your own to any assignment that you're given before seeking help from SO community. One such initial effort would be understanding completely what the question means.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the most popular algorithm for this, [Kadanes Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem).

As the algorithm states, I assume a non-empty array passed to it. Then I simply track the indices where the maximum sum begins and ends using two variables, `prev` and `curr`

```
int maxsubarray(int arr[])
{
    int maxsofar = arr[0], sum = arr[0], prev = 0, curr = 0;
    for i = 1 to arr.size

      //number greater than the addition of sums
      if(nums[i] > sum + nums[i]) prev = i;

      //maximum sum till this point in the array
      sum = max(nums[i], sum + nums[i])

      // if this is better than what we have so far
      if(sum > maxsofar)
          //store this sum and the array value
          maxsofar = sum
          curr = i

    print "start index of sum:", prev
    print "end index of sum:", curr

    // return the maximum value also found so far
    return maxsofar;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help - Actually i have to embed A[j : k] somewhere in my Maxsubfastest algorithm and i am unable to adjust or inset J:k into it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that... do you not want the indices of the range where the maximum sum occured?

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience , actually i am new to algorithm, and this is my assignment that "How can we output the indices j and k that identify the maximum subarray A[j : k]"

Comment: i have understand the algorithm but may be not getting the question.thanks